# Using Nginx as a web proxy?

Tags: proxy, nginx

My company does a lot of international advertising, and my boss wants a web proxy (that he can use with something like ProxySwitch firefox extension) in each of France, Spain, UK and Italy so that we can view/test our localized ads there.

We've already found VPS providers, now we're looking at implementation details; will Nginx work for this? I know it's used as a "reverse proxy" in load balancing situations, but how would I configure it to proxy the requests [from authorized hosts]?

Googling for "nginx proxy" gives me lots of ambiguous results. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you _required_ to use nginx?  You could use squid or apache probably to do this.

Comment: Not required, no, but with it's reputation as an awesome reverse-proxy, I thought it was probably the right tool for the job. I'll look into squid and apache as proxies, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx is a good reverse proxy, but I've never used it as a forward proxy, and I'm not sure it can even manage it.  I'd use Squid.

Comment: +1 for Squid. nginx is a REVERSE proxy.

Comment: Just installed Squid, solves the issue perfectly, took almost-zero configuration. Thanks!